# Error cvc-complex-type.2.4.d during XSD validation

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate some XML files with XSD schema but I get error cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid Content Was Found Starting With Element 'Number'. No Child Element Is Expected At This Point., Line '31', Column '11'.

This regards fields `Number` and `Description` that both inherit from `PrintableText` class.

I've already tried changing `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` in the `<xs:element />` objects but this results in the same behavoir.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Receipt>
  <Items>
    <FiscalItem>
      <Name>Przedmiot 1</Name>
      <ReturnablePackaging>false</ReturnablePackaging>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <PTU>A</PTU>
      <OriginalPrice>1.0</OriginalPrice>
      <Price>1.0</Price>
    </FiscalItem>
    <FiscalItem>
      <Name>Przedmiot 2</Name>
      <ReturnablePackaging>false</ReturnablePackaging>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <PTU>B</PTU>
      <OriginalPrice>1.0</OriginalPrice>
      <Price>5.0</Price>
    </FiscalItem>
  </Items>
  <Tedners>
    <FiscalTender>
      <Type>CASH</Type>
      <Amount>5.0</Amount>
    </FiscalTender>
    <FiscalTender>
      <Type>CREDITCARD</Type>
      <Amount>5.0</Amount>
    </FiscalTender>
  </Tedners>
  <!-- VVV THIS IS LINE VVV -->
  <Description>
    <Value>180</Value>
  </Description>
  <Number>
    <Value>12345</Value>
  </Number>
</Receipt>
```

XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Receipt" nillable="true" type="Receipt" />
  <xs:complexType name="Receipt">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="FiscalDocumentBase">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Number" type="ReceiptNumber" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description" type="ReceiptDescription" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="FiscalDocumentBase" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" name="Items" type="ArrayOfFiscalItem" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" name="Tedners" type="ArrayOfFiscalTender" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfFiscalItem">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="FiscalItem" nillable="true" type="FiscalItem" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="FiscalItem">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ReturnablePackaging" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Quantity" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PTU" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OriginalPrice" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Price" type="xs:decimal" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfFiscalTender">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="FiscalTender" nillable="true" type="FiscalTender" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="FiscalTender">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Type" type="FiscalTenderType" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Amount" type="xs:decimal" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="FiscalTenderType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="CASH" />
      <xs:enumeration value="CREDITCARD" />
      <xs:enumeration value="CHECK" />
      <xs:enumeration value="BOND" />
      <xs:enumeration value="CREDIT" />
      <xs:enumeration value="OTHER" />
      <xs:enumeration value="VOUCHER" />
      <xs:enumeration value="ACCOUNT" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="PrintableText">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ReceiptNumber">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="PrintableText" />
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ReceiptDescription">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="PrintableText" />
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

EDIT: removing the `Number` field results in a passed validation.

Comment: Consider adding a comment to your XML that looks like: `<!-- This is line 31 -->`

Comment: @Flydog57 done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... so my friend found the issue. In the XSD schema the order of elements should be different.

Original:

```
...
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Number" type="ReceiptNumber" />
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description" type="ReceiptDescription" />
...
```

Fixed:

```
...
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description" type="ReceiptDescription" />
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Number" type="ReceiptNumber" />    
...
```

Comment: Don't forget to use the green tick next to your answer to show that this is what solved your problem.